# AWK split a large file into thousand mini files error

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a very large file that I need to split into thousand mini files and this is the error I am getting:

> A maximum of 2042 files can be open at one time.  The input line
>   number is 144620. The file is help.txt.  The source line number is 1.

Here is my code to split the large file:

```
awk '/HELP./{x="Count"++i;}{print > x;}'  help.txt
```

Any ideas on how I can get pass this error?

Comment: Does `close(x)` after print help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should close each file after you are finished with them:

```
/HELP./{if (x) close (x); x="Count"++i}{print > x}
```

Comment: @hek2mgl But I think the two rules should not be joined. The first, is only for lines matching `HELP`, the second is executed for all lines..

Comment: Ah, I see. Btw, I didn't knew that close is required here. Learned that.

Comment: @hek2mgl close() is only required in this situation if you aren't using GNU awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thx for that information! I tried (with GNU awk) using xxxxxxxx files and couldn't reproduce that. :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland +!. FYI you don't NEED the `if (x)` as `close()` is required to do nothing if called with no arg or an arg that doesn't represent an open file.